# how to make an array with my struct types?

Tags: c, arrays, data-structures

In C#.NET I can to use `List<myclasstype> vals = new List<myclasstype> ();` it's possible do equivalent to in C?

I have an struct like:

```
typedef struct foo {
    int x;
    int y;
} Baa;
```

and I want do:

```
**BAA vals = ?? 
int i ;
for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
   vals[i].x = i;
   vals[i].y = i * 10;
}
```

I hope this is clear for you. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is the same as you would create any other array in C except that the type is replaced with `Baa`

```
int size = 5;
Baa baaArray[size];

int i;
for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
   baaArray[i].x = i;
   baaArray[i].y = i*10;
}
```

You can also use pointers and malloc to accomplish this:

```
int size = 5;
Baa *baaPtr = malloc(sizeof(Baa) * size);

//...
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Please keep in mind that using variable-sized arrays automatically makes your code C99 - use a compiler that supports it.

Comment: wouldn't the length of `size` be known at compile time? since I declare it to be 5?

Comment: `size` is not declared explicitly as `const`.